# select field works without button but it dont change in select field

Tags: javascript

I want to change content information of my website by selecting from select field. If I select any item my information be changed but in select field remain the same item all the time. please help me to keep selected item along with changing information.

Comment: Share your code at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward to me.

[Check out this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/mM3dU/) Hope this helps

Try logging the `selectedIndex` of the select option in your case.